# Amazon s3 and buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, buckets

I created an amazon instance and i'm currently able to login through SSH.
I've uploaded some files through terminal using scp. Additionally, I created a bucket and uploaded some files that way. I don't see those files in my terminal. Apparently they are stored in different places..??

What's the connection between buckets and my instance?

Can someone please give me the quick and dirty about this and maybe anything else i need to know about building on aws.

Comment: How did you upload those files to S3 bucket?

Comment: Through their console, which is painfully slow. How do i upload to my bucket and how come i don't see my bucket in linux terminal?

Comment: Generally speaking, Instances are servers where your code will lie and execute to produce results. S3 Buckets are the places where your files would lie(if you choose to).  A rough analogy would be, Instance : your PC, Buckets : your NAS.

Comment: Basically if it's a staic website you are trying to host on AWS S3, you don't even need the EC2 instance. Check out this AWS documentation on hosting static websites on S3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to install AWS Command Line interface for seeing the content of the bucket from your instance terminal.

Check this AWS CLI Installation and Usage guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html

And this are the commands for using with AWS S3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Comment: Well what about the stuff i uploaded through my standard linux terminal and my instance of ubuntu? I can't just use that to publish things to a website? I have to use the bucket to publish stuff to the end point?

Comment: So you can copy that content from the Instance to S3 bucket from the command line? Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve from EC2 Instance and S3 Bucket so it will make things clear? But answer to your question is above.

Comment: Well i was thinking i could run a website off the instance, no?

Comment: I uploaded my files and figured I could use the endpoint to display my site. Then i read that i have to upload my files to a bucket which is separate from the instance. I'm confused now to what i'm supposed to be doing with the instance now that i have the bucket.

Comment: What's the Instance ID for? Simply to connect through terminal? I've done that already and was able to SCP files. Fair enough.... so what's the public NDS and public IP for? If i copy and paste them into a browser i get nothing.

Comment: So you are mixing lots of things here Endpoints are for AWS Cloudfront. Check this guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/web-app-hosting-intro.html this will make things clear for website hosting.

Comment: Okay, sorry to be so confusing. I have my EC2 all setup. What's next for using EC2 to build my site? And where do i go to visit the front of my site in a browser?

Comment: I guess it's more than you're willing to explain. I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: What website are you setting up Give the details like OS PHP wordpress or some thing else so I can explain clearly.

Comment: Sure, it's a magento build 2.0 i'm using ubuntu and i just installed nginx on my EC2 instance. Additionally, all my files are already on the ec2 as well. I just can't figure out what the url would be to view my web/app on the fontend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116845/discussion-between-thismethod-and-error2007s).